# Finding the rank of a matrix based on a variable

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

How can I find the rank of the matrix 
$B_{a} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -1 & 0 & 1\\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & -1\\ 
a & 1 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & a & 1
\end{bmatrix}$ based on the possible values of $a$?

Comment: With the minors criterion.

Comment: Computing determinants is usually a waste of time, even more if you are going to compute many. Do Gauss elimination, just like always. For example, use the $1$ in the second row, first column to kill the $-1$ and the $a$ in the first column. then use the $1$ in the last row second column to kill all other non-zero entries in the second column. The matrix might look something like this $\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&1\\1&1&0&1\\0&1-a&1&a\\0&1&a&1\end{pmatrix}$ after the first step.

Comment: After the second step is can look like $\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&1\\1&0&-a&0\\0&0&1-a(1-a)&a-(1-a)\\0&1&a&1\end{pmatrix}$. Already you can see the rank information. If $1-a(1-a)\neq0$, then it will have full rank. If $1-a(1-a)=0$, then the first row can be used to completely kill the third row and we get rank $3$.

Comment: Where do the coefficients live?

Comment: @OscarRascal This solved it for me! thank you :)

Comment: The rank is obviously at most 3: compare the first and second rows.